# curl, отправленые заголовки

Tags: curl, php

Возможно ли посмотреть весь запрос который отправил CURL? Ибо нужно для отладки

Comment: Через Firebug в Mozilla, либо другие приложения для отладки в браузерах. Только в Mozilla просмоторщик заголовков нужно найти как дополнение или плагин.
Введите в поиске headers / HTTP headers там выдаст.

Comment: @GenchiK причем тут клиентские приложения и curl? В firebug можно посмотреть заголовки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[curl_getinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php)